# Toroids low magnetic field is only for the core?

Tags: transformer

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Here is a thing. When I connect it as 120v (parallel), the magnetic field outside the core is much lesser than when connected as 240v (series). The load of both is same 100v-256v autovolt LG OLED TV (just for testing).

Does it mean when connecting as 240v series, the windings don't have uniform current? Why? How?

It's for this model http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/VPM240-2080.pdf, a 500va medical isolation transformer I bought to protect my bench project troubleshooting.

Comment: Maybe the magnetic field you are measuring is due to currnet flowing in the wire that is connected to the core? You could replace the transformer with a resistor and measure again.

Comment: Did you forget that a transformer with an external load projects magnetic fields from the wires going to the load, not the toroid itself. No rules were broken here.

Comment: No, the wires are flat cord so the magnetic field is self cancelling, like in GFCI. So the source of the magnetic field is really the windings of the toroids.

Comment: flat cord is not totally self-cancelling; if very close (e,g,the center-center), you'll measure 1/1 - 1/2 = 50% cancelling. At 10x the center-center, expect 90% cancellation (20 dB reduction)

Comment: I have measured the wires.. it is not the wires but the windings magnetic field. Theoretically why would windings of toroid transformer produce less magnetic field than traditional EI cores?

Comment: First off, contact Triad and ask them. They are the manufacturer of your toroid. They should be able to help answer your questions. (At this point, from your comments, I take it that you consider yourself an expert in measuring fields. So I will leave that question for others.) Second, it should be quite obvious why a toroid shape, in theory, should leak less flux. If it isn't obvious, just note that by Ampere's law the intensity of the B field must be zero outside the toroidal windings. Of course, practice is another thing.

Comment: @Jtl   A toroid can be wound on a plan that goes both around the minor diameter AND takes one or more turns around the major hole, or can go around the minor diameter and take zero turns around the major hole.    The latter winding scheme has, except for irregular core properties or geometry, zero external field.

Comment: Any illustrations of this minor diameter and major hole thing that show how magnetic fields in windings in toroidal core gets cancelled?

Comment: Everyone here is considering 50/60 Hz magnetic fields. Does your magnetic field measurement discriminate between 50/60 and possible harmonics? Could you be measuring mostly high-frequency components?

Comment: I used this meter https://www.amazon.com/TriField-EMF-Meter-Model-TF2/dp/B078T2R64C/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1546129728&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=trifield+meter&psc=1 spec is "AC Magnetic: 3-axis, true magnitude.
Frequency Range:40 Hz – 100 kHz.
Accuracy: ±4% @ 50/60 Hz.
Maximum Range: 100.0 milligauss.
Sensivity (Resolution): 0.1 milligauss."  Know any model more accurate than this?  Well at half meter (about 1.64 feet), the meter can measure about 15milligauss. Are you guys saying that in toroids, it shouldn't leak even 1 milligauss half a meter away?

Comment: @Jtl  There's no 'fields...in toroidal core' being cancelled, those are reinforced.   It's EXTERNAL to the toroid core that fields are cancelled, unless the windings include a loop/loops around the center hole (which genertes the same external B field, roughly, as any current loop).

Comment: I have learnt since that fields being zero outside toroidal core is only for perfect or ideal toroid core. But in real world, there is leaked field due to the windings not exactly symmetrical down to micrometers, etc.