# Toroids side cover magnetic induction

Tags: transformer

I plan to put a metal cover to the bare toroid transformer, but the sides would be almost touching (I couldn't find other chassis around). I'm aware the bolt at middle musn't be connected (or shorted to top case) to avoid shorted turn. But with sides almost touching metal chasses, how much current would be inducted or lost to the metal cover?

[image: 1]

This is the spec of the toroid transformer. Generally, what must be the clearance in the sides for the metal case, and what negative effects if its' touching?

[image: 2]

Comment: To get an answer to your question you'll need to provide all ratings for the transformer, load and power source, however, it might be better to ask how to calculate or determine how much clearance *you need*.  If you can't find a suitable case, it's time consuming but not difficult to build one from sheet metal and angle iron.  You'd need a drill, hacksaw, tin snips/nibbler and file of course.

Comment: see edited post or https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/924/mCNw0s.jpg  No, I won't create one from scratch.. just need to use old metal cases lying around. So how do you calculate or determine how much clearance in the sides one needs?

Comment: Recycling is just fine if you have suitable parts available =).  If you want to change your question, or ask it both ways, click the "edit" button at the bottom.  You should include the image you just linked me to with the transformer ratings in the question, as well as all other relevant information, such as your source voltage and output voltage and maximum expected current.  This way all the necessary info is nice and together and won't be lost if the site purges old comments.

Comment: Unfortunately I know enough to know what givens you need for a solution, but not enough to help you solve so this will have to wait until one of the suitable engineers comes by.  By the time one of those guys arrive, you'll want to edit your question enough so he thinks "Nice question!  This will be fun to answer!" and then you'll usually get a pretty impressive response.  If you would like to start messing around with a *tool* that I know is capable of a solution to your problem, check out Finite Element Magnetic Modeller(FEMM) tool.  Sadly I've not modelled something like this myself.

Answer (score 2):

A uniformly wound toroid has no external magnetic field, regardless of the core permeability.

In a non-uniformly wound one, the external field is reduced by the core permability.

Given that most commercial toroidal transformers are wound relatively uniformly (for all sorts of good practical and financial reasons), and that the core permeability is generally in the 1000s, the external field of a toroidal transformer can be neglected, at least for gross worries like reducing the transformer efficiency or heating the cover. Even for fine worries, like inducing signal voltages in the inputs of amplifiers, a commercial toroid is usually good enough.

A toroidal is an order of magnitude or two better than an EI or a C-core power transformer on external field, as the latter types tend to have some small air-gap where the parts of the core meet, making for a non-uniform core. A toroid cannot help but be gapless, however well or badly assembled.

Comment: But if you will use a magnetic field meter, you can measure about 100 milligauss outside the toroid. So there is still residual magnetic field. What do you think about 100 milligauss?

Comment: What do I think about 100mG? I think it's about 0.1G. What do you think about 100mG? No, seriously, 0.1G is about 10 micro Tesla, and there's more than 1T inside the toroid, so an attenuation factor of 100,000 times. Which it why it won't heat the metal, or affect the transformer efficiency at all, not the slightest jot, not one iota. It *may* pick up into amplifier inputs, if they're sensitive enough.

Comment: At half meter away from the toroid..there is still about 15  millgauss i measured. Are.there 500va toroid that would produce zero magnetic field outside the core. Why doesnt it cancel? Pls see related post at  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414241/toroids-low-magnetic-field-is-only-for-the-core?noredirect=1#comment1024345_414241  and if possible kindly answer it..tnx

Comment: you can't have *zero* field, at any distance. You can field attenuated 10k times by conventional EI transformer, 100k times by toroidal with commercial grade windings, perhaps 1M times by toroidal with windings carefully wound for best uniformity (rather than relatively uniformly), maybe 10M or even 100M by the previous with a mumetal shield. But not zero. An then there's the input/output wires to consider, tightly twisted at a minimum, ideally co-axial if you're looking for very low field.

Comment: see updated https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414241/toroids-low-magnetic-field-is-only-for-the-core When I connect it as 120v (parallel), the magnetic field outside the core is much lesser than when connected as 240v (series). The load of both is same 100v-256v autovolt LG OLED TV (just for testing).
Does it mean when connecting as 240v series, the windings don't have uniform current? Why? How?

Comment: Have you met the spherical cow in a vacuum? It's an idealisation. Similarly, a uniformly-wound toroid is ideal. A real toroid will depart from that, even if carefully wound. If wound as a mains transformer, with no care for symmetry, as your one has been, it could depart a long way from uniformity. You are getting a very good low field reading from it. Changes as you reconfigure series/parallel are totally unsurprising, and without knowing exactly where every wire in and out is, unpredictable. There is nothing more theory or I can say, measurement of the remaining residuals is down to you.